Collision control between balloon strings

I’m trying to avoid the strings of the balloons glitching into the balloons. The balloons themselves have an active rigid body modifier and are attached to a cube with a passive rigid body modifier. The strings are attached to the balloons using a hook to selected effect.

Have you tried adding a collision modifier to the balloons?
